# Как создать цикл вывода сообщения? Раз в 5-10 минут?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Разрабатываю бота на nodejs.
Нужно чтобы бот выводил 1 сообщение раз в 5-10 минут например.
Через что это реализовать?

Comment: А в чем у вас проблема? Как вы пробовали ее уже решать? Пробовали вы реализовать это через методы объекта Date ?

Comment: Исправлюсь,имел ввиду setTimout или setInterval

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=node+scheduler

Comment: Опиши функцию для вывода сообщения и вызывай ее через `setInterval` раз в 5 - 10 минут.